# How do I read a binary file of n record using c

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

I have a code that writes n records of profiles into a binary file but when I try to read from it and print on the console it doesn't work and goes into an infinite loop here's my code:

```
/*profile strucre */
struct profile 
{
  char name[30];
  int phoneNumber;
} pr;


int main()
{
   int rn; 
   FILE *fp; //le fichier
   printf("\nHow many profiles would you like to have?");
   scanf("%d", &rn);
   struct profile p[rn];
   for (int i = 0; i < rn; i++)
 {
 printf("\nEnter the name no %d: ", i+1);
 scanf("%s", p[i].name);
 printf("\nEnter the name phone number %d: ", i+1);
 scanf("%d", &p[i].phoneNumber);
 }

 //file creation 
 for (int i = 0; i < rn; i++)
 {
  fp = fopen ("profiles.bin", "wb");
  if (fp != NULL)
  {
    fwrite (&p[i], sizeof (p[i]), 1, fp);
    fclose (fp);
  }
 }

/* file reading */
    if(fp==NULL) //if the file doesnt existe
    {
        printf("File could not open");
        exit(0); //EXIT SUCCESS
    }
    int j = 1;
    while((fread(&pr,sizeof(pr),1,fp)!= EOF)) //this doesnt work
    {
      printf("\nRecord No:%d",j);
      printf("\n------------------");
      printf("\nName:%s",pr.name);
      printf("\nPhone number:%d",pr.phoneNumber);
      printf("\n=======================");
      j++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    
}
```

output is:

```
=======================
Record No:3728
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3729
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3730
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3731
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3732
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3733
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3734
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3735
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3736
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3737
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3738
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3739
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3740
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3741
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3742
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3743
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3744
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3745
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3746
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3747
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3748
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3749
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3750
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3751
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3752
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3753
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
=======================
Record No:3754
------------------
Name:
Phone number:0
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must provide complete code as a [mre]. Please update the question with complete code that anyone can run exactly as shown to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Don't omit important code, like how you opened the file and how you checked for errors.

Comment: The file creation is wrong as it opens and closes the file every iteration. Which means it is overwriting the start of the file every time. Then the reading is also wrong as it does not open the file.

Comment: Check the manual page for `fread()`. Can it return `EOF` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  fp = fopen ("profiles.bin", "wb");
  if (fp != NULL)
  {
    fwrite (&p[i], sizeof (p[i]), 1, fp);
    fclose (fp);
  }
```

You close and overwrite your file every time. So you have only one record there.

You need to move the closing out of the loop.

```
  fp = fopen ("profiles.bin", "wb");
  if (fp != NULL)
  {
    fwrite (&p[i], sizeof (p[i]), 1, fp); 
    // add some error checking
  }
  fclose (fp);
```

Also you need to open file for reading (as it was closed)

```
  fp = fopen ("profiles.bin", "rb");
/* file reading */
    if(fp==NULL) //if the file doesnt exist
```

Comment: I am getting an output now but it's only the last record and it's still going in an infinite loop